# If statement with an unknown amount of conditions

Tags: java, if-statement, dictionary

I am working on a small application, where I am trying to have an object (`Property`) be put into an `ArrayList<Property>`. Basically I'm making a search function that operates on a `Map` of what to search for.

E.g.: I want to search for all Properties with name `"12 Hello Lane"` that were listed between 2013 and 2015.

I would then do like so:

```
for (Property p : properties){
    if (p.getName().equals("12 Hello Lane") && p.getListingDate().getYear() >=2013 && p.getListingDate().getYear() <= 2015){
        //Add to list
    }
}
```

The problem being, I am passing a `Map` of properties to compare, the key being the method name and the value being the desired value. In other words:

```
Key: "getName"
Value: "12 Hello Lane"
Key: "getYear"
Value: 2013-2015
...
```

My question is how do I make it so that I can use a single if statement to cover all the properties? Something like:

```
for (Property p : properties){
    if (p.getClass().getMethod(options.getKey()) == options.getValue()){
        //Add to list
    }
}
```

I don't know if I'm phrasing this correctly, but I hope you guys get my drift.

EDIT: I am trying to achieve an effect of `if a AND b AND c...`. Just thought I would clarify, as I see that many answers are giving something more akin to an `OR`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reasonably close:

- Your approach amounts to an `OR`, rather than an `AND`. If you would like an `AND`, make a flag, set it in the loop, and check it once the loop is over
- You are not calling reflection correctly.

Here is how you should be able to do it:

```
List<Data> allItems = ...
List<Data> filtered = new ArrayList<>();
for (Data d : allItems) {
    boolean allPass = true;
    for (Map.Entry<String,String> entry : propertyMap.entrySet()) {
        Method m = d.getClass().getMethod(entry.getKey());
        if (m == null || !entry.getValue().equals(m.invoke(d))){
            allPass = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (allPass) {
        filtered.add(d);
    }
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/K4hw1z)

Comment: Thanks. I'll check this in the morning (feeling a bit tired...). But it seems that this will work...

Comment: @Riccorbypro No problem! Click on the demo link, you should be able to see what's going on, and if this is something you are looking for. Good night!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, because of all the answers that are trying to do magic ... here is my suggestion.

What you actually want is a [Matcher](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html)

Each matcher looks like this... For example for matching a name:

```
private static Matcher<Property> withName(final String name) {
    return new BaseMatcher<Property>() {

        public void describeTo(Description description) {
            description.appendText("Matches property name to ").appendValue(name);
        }

        public boolean matches(Object o) {
            Property p = (Property) o;
            return p.name.equals(name);
        }
    };
}
```

Then you'll have a number of matchers (for address, year, etc.) and an actual filter method that will apply all those criterias to the list:

```
public List<Property> filter(Matcher<Property>... matchers) {
    List<Property> valid = new ArrayList<Property>(); //valid ones to return
    propertyLoop: for (Property property : propertyList) {
        for (Matcher<Property> matcher : matchers) {
            if (matcher.matches(property)) {
                valid.add(property);
            } else {
                continue propertyLoop;
        }
    }
    return valid;
}
```

Hence your final code looks similar to that:

```
List<Property> machingProperties = filter(withName("12 Hello Lane"), withYear(2012, 2015));
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work correctly for what I need, but I'll check this one as well.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I just wonder how these situations come to exist.
This is the general idea:

```
for (Property p: properties) {
    boolean shouldAdd = true;
    for (String method: options.keySet()) {
        if (p.getClass().getMethod(method).invoke(p) != options.get(key)) { 
            shouldAdd = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (shouldAdd) {
       //add to list 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your requirements, it sounds like you need is some kind of predicate builder.  You'll need to write some code that creates these predicates I'm showing below, then you can loop over them and call evaluate.  I've implemented one of the cases you'd need.

```
interface Predicate {

    boolean evaluate();

}

class StringComparePredicate implements Predicate {

    final String key;
    final String value;

    StringComparePredicate(String key, String value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }    

    @Override
    boolean evaluate() {
        return this.key.equals(this.value);
    }
}
```

and one for comparing dates, etc.  Then you can call your for loop and run evaluate on each of the predicates.

Answer (score 0):

I got confused at first because of the double-entendre of the word "Property". You could make another class, called **PropertyAttribute**, as such:

```
public class PropertyAttribute {
    private String name;
    private Object value;

    public PropertyAttribute(String name, Object value) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }

    // Applicable getters and setters...
}
```

So then within **Property** you can store a list of **PropertyAttributes**:

```
public class Property {
    public List<PropertyAttribute> attributes = new ArrayList<PropertyAttribute>();

    public Property() {
        // Add to attributes, like:
        attributes.add(new PropertyAttribute("name", "12 Hello Lane"));
        attributes.add(new PropertyAttribute("year", "2013 - 2015"));
    }
}
```

Then finally you can search like:

```
for(Property p : properties) {
     for(PropertyAttribute attr : p.attributes) {
         if(options.getKey() == attr.getName() && options.getValue() == attr.getValue) {
             // add to list.
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this would require a major re-structure of my Objects, as my `Property` object currently has the attributes as variables inside the object class. Are you suggesting I have each property have a list of attributes, with each attribute set to as a key/value?

Comment: Upon re-reading, I see that this approach amounts to an `OR` statement rather than an `AND`. I'm trying to achieve an `AND`.